# Is it possible to NOT display NAs in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am trying to create a data.frame where some cells have missing values. Instead of showing NAs, I wonder if there is any way to hide the NAs? What I want essentially is like an ANOVA table as shown below.

```
 x = rnorm(40)    
 y = rep(1:2, each=20)    
 z = rep(c(1,2,1,2), each=10)  
 model1 = lm(x~y * z)  
 model2 = lm(x~y + z)  
 anova(model1, model2)  

 #Analysis of Variance Table
 #Model 1: x ~ y * z
 #Model 2: x ~ y + z
 #Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
 #1     36 38.931                           
 #2     37 39.248 -1  -0.31705 0.2932 0.5915
```

The output is above. If you try to access those blank cells, you will get NAs

```
 anova(model1, model2)[1,4]
 #[1] NA
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm confused - when you do `anova(model1,model2)` the NAs in the returned object (for example in `[1,4]` as you noted) are *not* shown, as you requested. So what do you mean by "not show"? What are you doing that shows them?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. I am trying to make a table for the output of a script I am writing. But NAs are always shown as NAs as opposed to being hidden as in the anova() output. So basically I would like my output table to be just like anova() output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print.anova` works by using the `na.print` option of `print.default`, like this:

```
> x <- matrix(c(101:111/100, NA), nrow=3)
> print(x, na.print="")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1.01 1.04 1.07 1.10
[2,] 1.02 1.05 1.08 1.11
[3,] 1.03 1.06 1.09
```

However, this only works for matrices, not for data frames.

For data frames, the suggestion of replacing the NA's with "" is good, but loses the usual printing of digits; you can do so by using `format.data.frame` before replacement. Read the `print.data.frame` function for more details.  Doing it this way, you can also replace with NA and then use the `na.print` option, as above.

```
> y <- as.data.frame(x)
> m <- as.matrix(format.data.frame(y, digits = NULL, na.encode = FALSE))
> m[is.na(y)] <- NA
> print(m, na.print="", quote=FALSE)
  V1   V2   V3   V4  
1 1.01 1.04 1.07 1.10
2 1.02 1.05 1.08 1.11
3 1.03 1.06 1.09
```

See how the digits in the fourth column line up?  Compare to this.

```
> z <- y
> z[is.na(z)] <- ""
> print(z)
    V1   V2   V3   V4
1 1.01 1.04 1.07  1.1
2 1.02 1.05 1.08 1.11
3 1.03 1.06 1.09
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually don't mind using matrices. I decided to just change the rownames to make it look better and less matrix-like. I thought about replacing NAs with "" before, but decided against it because I would like the output to be readily accessible as numerics.

Comment: Glad to help.  If this answer has solved your problem, please click the check mark to let others know both that it was helpful to you and that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing.  But I think you have a table with NAs and you don't want the NAs to appear like in the anova table you gave?  If this is correct you can index to find the NAs and replace with "":

```
(w <- data.frame(anova(model1, model2))) #your example as a data frame with NAs
w[is.na(w)] <- ""                        #index to find NAs and replace with ""
w
```

Comment: I actually want my table to look like anova tables...sorry for having not made it clear. But normally, NAs in data frames are visible, and I *do not* want them to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's answer (which is a good one) relies on `print.default` -- I found this less than ideal because I needed to use `row.names = FALSE`, which is supported only in `print.data.table`.  (And `quote=FALSE` is the default on `print.data.table`, so one less thing to worry about there.)

You don't have to convert your data.table to a matrix, you can convert it to a list of character and back to a data.frame, like this:

```
prettyPrintDf <- function(df, ...) # My function
  print(format.data.frame(data.frame(lapply(df, as.character)), na.encode = FALSE), 
        na.print="", ...)
```

So given a data.frame like

```
some_df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA), b = c(4,NA,6), c = letters[1:3])
```

You can do:

```
> prettyPrintDf(some_df, row.names=FALSE)
 a b c
 1 4 a
 2   b
   6 c
```